# how to remove "today" from calendar footer of input type date

Tags: html, input, calendar

Just want to remove the today link from the calendar footer because I am selecting the future date so, no need of showing today in calendar footer.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I believe it depends on the browser. Not sure if anything can be done about it.

Comment: Hello Sunny Yadav, welcome to stackoverflow. Are you using a jquery calendar, or something built-into a framework of some kind? You should provide code, if there is any. There is very little chance we can help you solve your problem if there is no code.

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64 Educated guess, looks like they're using the built-in HTML5 date control in Edge Chromium, going by the tags. The control in that browser looks the exact same as the image provided.

Answer (score 1):

The display of the HTML5 date control depends on the browser. For example, Chrome, Opera, Firefox and Edge Spartan don't show a "Today" button (and can have a variety of different layouts), while Edge Chromium does.

Unfortunately there's no standardized attribute which lets you control how these calendars are rendered. If you really need to get rid of the Today button from your calendars, you may need to consider using a JavaScript/CSS-powered date picker, such as the ones provided in [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and other such frameworks, which have varying degrees of flexibility in how calendars are rendered.

Comment: unfortunately "not using the built-in calendars" seems to be the correct approach if you want to configure or change its attributes. jQuery seems horrendously outdated, but it does simple things like calendar date pickers actually pretty swimmingly. for over one and a half decades now...

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a messy workaround, but for Edge Chromium in particular you can set the `min` attribute to something that's greater than today's date. This won't remove the Today button, but will make it so that the user can't select it or any other date before the `min` date.

```
<!-- Set the value of min to something after today's date -->
<input type="date" min="2020-08-01" />
```